# Need rownum to be the same for for each record between two queries that query the same tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that store user action data (almost exact same structure). Users could be in one of the tables but not the other or in both tables (or in neither).

I have two queries, which query both tables via UNION ALL. I need the same number of records in each query, with the ROWNUM the same per user record between both data sets.

I reverse the union between the two queries, order them the same. However, the rownums are different even though the data should be retrieved in the same order. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

(I'm feeding this data into a graph\chart component in which ROWNUM is required to work properly)

Query 1

```
SELECT ROWNUM, cnt, opno FROM ( 
   SELECT SUM(fieldct) cnt, opno 
   FROM operchgeedp 
   WHERE opno <  997 
   AND LOWER(prognm) = 'eedpmain.exe' 
   AND TRUNC(begdtt) BETWEEN DATE'2019-02-01' 
   AND  TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
   GROUP BY opno 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 0 cnt, opno 
   FROM operchgprv 
   WHERE opno NOT IN (
      SELECT opno 
      FROM operchgeedp 
      WHERE opno <  997 
      AND LOWER(prognm) = 'eedpmain.exe' 
      AND TRUNC(begdtt) BETWEEN DATE'2019-02-01' 
      AND  TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
   )
   AND TRUNC(begdtt) BETWEEN DATE'2019-02-01' 
   AND  TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
   AND opno <  997 
   GROUP BY opno )
ORDER BY opno`
```

Query 2

```
SELECT ROWNUM, cnt, opno FROM ( 
   SELECT SUM(fieldct) cnt, opno 
   FROM operchgprv 
   WHERE opno <  997 
   AND LOWER(prognm) = 'prvmain.exe' 
   AND TRUNC(begdtt) BETWEEN DATE'2019-02-01' 
   AND  TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
   GROUP BY opno 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 0 cnt, opno 
   FROM operchgeedp 
   WHERE opno NOT IN (
      SELECT opno 
      FROM operchgprv 
      WHERE opno <  997 
      AND LOWER(prognm) = 'prvmain.exe' 
      AND TRUNC(begdtt) BETWEEN DATE'2019-02-01' 
      AND  TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
   ) 
   AND TRUNC(begdtt) BETWEEN DATE'2019-02-01' 
   AND  TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
   AND opno <  997 
   GROUP BY opno )
ORDER BY opno`
```

[image: Query1]

[image: Query 2]

Comment: rownum cannot give you consistency if data is added or deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROWNUM isn't necessarily consistent because it's not a stored value.  That said, for your purposes, you may get the result you want by moving the ORDER BY inside the () block.

select rownum, cnt, opno from (
...
order by opno);

Alternatively you can try to use the RANK analytics function:
select rank() over (order by opno), cnt, opno from (...);

Comment: Moving the ORDER BY worked. Thank you very much. I had tried that before but on both of the unioned queries. Which causes an error with the group by. But yes, the one order by at the end within the primary (). Thanks again!